# Place array elements randomly inside container element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of divs that are currently resized (according to text inside the div) and then appended to container on a button click event.  I'm using an algorithm to randomly sort the array and I would like to place it inside the containing div in that order.

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('.box').draggable();
            var boxArray = $('.box');
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function ()
            {
                randomizeArray(boxArray);
                $('.box').each(function ()
                {
                    $(this).appendTo('#itemContainer');

                });
            });

            //shuffle the array randomly
            function randomizeArray(array)
            {
                var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

                // While there remain elements to shuffle...
                while (0 !== currentIndex)
                {

                    // Pick a remaining element...
                    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
                    currentIndex -= 1;

                    // And swap it with the current element.
                    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
                    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
                    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
                }

                return array;
            }
```

HTML

```
 <div id="boxContainer">
    <div class="box">
        <div>Item1 - 40</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div>
            Item2 - 20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div>
            Item3 - 90</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div>
            Item4 - 60</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div>
            Item5 - 70</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="itemContainer">
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
}
.box
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    min-width:40px;
    min-height:40px;
}
#itemContainer
{
    float:right;
    width:600px;
    height:800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#boxContainer
{
    float:left;
}
#itemContainer div
{
    float:left;
}
```

Is there going to be an easy way to solve this?  I thought of having as many hidden divs as the array holds inside container div and use something like index of the array to append to the ID of the hidden div.  Is there an easier way to randomly sort an array of divs than that?

Comment: What about just looping through the array of divs and `$('#divToAppendTo').append(arrayDiv[i]);` ?

Comment: `boxArray = randomizeArray(boxArray);boxArray.each(function ()`

Comment: @RobSchmuecker well, I was going to make that much harder than I should have.  That works great, and is streamlined and simple.  Gracias.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie only a pleasure :-) Glad to have helped!